# How to traverse files in Android directories in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying to traverse the contents of **DCIM** but to no success.

The attempt below can only read **folders** but never recursively gets into them like I'm trying to.

**DCIM** does have files inside it.

How can I traverse files in a directory in **Android** with React Native?

```
function walkSync(currentDirPath, callback) {
  RNFS.readDir(currentDirPath).then(result => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      let file = result[i];

      var filePath = currentDirPath + '/' + file.name;

      console.log('filePath : ' + filePath);

      RNFS.stat(filePath).then(statResult => {
        if (statResult.isFile()) {
          console.log('F : ' + filePath);

          callback(filePath, statResult);
        } else if (statResult.isDirectory()) {
          console.log('DIR : ' + filePath);

          walkSync(filePath, callback);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

walkSync(
  RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/DCIM',
  function (filePath, stat) {
    console.log(filePath + ' : ' + stat.isFile());
  },
);
```

Thank you all in advance.